# jQuery: Find matching attribute values across two sets of lists and then move individual list items accordingly

Tags: jquery, list, attributes, comparison

I am working with two different classes of unordered lists (a *Categories* class and a *Sections* class). Each `<li>` instance in the Categories list has a 'catid' attribute with a specific numeric value assignment. Each `<li>` instance in the Sections list has a 'categoryid' attribute with a specific numeric value assignment. The abbreviated code snippet below illustrates this construction:

```
<ul id = "categories">
<li class="cat" catid="360002254991"><a>Category A</a></li>

<li class="cat" catid="360002255011"><a>Category B</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sections">
<li class="sec" secid="360008584672" categoryid="360002246652"><a href="https://myURL">Section 1</a></li>

<li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002255011"><a href="https://myURL">Section 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need a programmatic way to look at ALL `<li>` instances across both of the parent unordered lists (Categories / Sections) and find all matches between 'catid' values and 'categoryid' values.

Once the matches are found, I will then need to move each Section list item (class of 'sec') so that it sits directly beneath the matching Category list item (class of 'cat'). I am assuming that this will be accomplished with the *insertAfter* method.

To reiterate my challenge in 'logical' terms: I need to compare all members of two sets (Category and Section) to identify matching numeric values across two different attributes ('catid' and 'categoryid'). Once the matches are identified, I then need to move all members from the Section set so that each one sits directly beneath the matching member from the Category set.

I get the logic, I just do not know the exact coding syntax and how to construct the conditional jQuery statements needed to run the comparison and then move the `<li>` items accordingly.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(".sec").each(function() {
  let catid = $(this).attr("categoryid");
  $(".cat").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("catid") == catid) {
      $(".sec[categoryid=" + catid + "]").insertAfter($(".cat[catid=" + catid + "]"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="categories">
  <li class="cat" catid="360002254991"><a>Category A</a></li>
  <li class="cat" catid="360002255011"><a>Category B</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="sections">
  <li class="sec" secid="360008584672" categoryid="360002246652"><a href="https://myURL">Section 1</a></li>
  <li class="sec" secid="360007912231" categoryid="360002255011"><a href="https://myURL">Section 2</a></li>
</ul>
```